# MISMATCHED_SEARCH_PARENTHESIS : Search error: Parentheses are unbalanced

Tags: javascript, netsuite

When I run `testThatFails` below I get the following error:

> MISMATCHED_SEARCH_PARENTHESIS : Search error: Parentheses are unbalanced.

Why am I getting that error?

If I change `is` to `haskeywords`, it works (`testThatSucceeds`).

If I take out `,"AND",["line","equalto","1"]`, it works (`anotherTestThatSucceeds`).

If I change `numbertext` to `number`, it works (`yetAnotherTestThatSucceeds`).

```
define(['N/search'], function (nSearch) {

    function testThatFails() {
        var objSearch = nSearch.create({
            type: 'transaction',
            filters: [[["numbertext","is","1"],"AND",["line","equalto","1"]]],
            columns: [nSearch.createColumn({
                name: 'internalid'
            })]
        });

        var resultSet = objSearch.run();

        resultSet.getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
    }

    function testThatSucceeds() {
        var objSearch = nSearch.create({
            type: 'transaction',
            filters: [[["numbertext","haskeywords","1"],"AND",["line","equalto","1"]]],
            columns: [nSearch.createColumn({
                name: 'internalid'
            })]
        });

        var resultSet = objSearch.run();

        resultSet.getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
    }

    function anotherTestThatSucceeds() {
        var objSearch = nSearch.create({
            type: 'transaction',
            filters: [[["numbertext","is","1"]]],
            columns: [nSearch.createColumn({
                name: 'internalid'
            })]
        });

        var resultSet = objSearch.run();

        resultSet.getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
    }

    function yetAnotherTestThatSucceeds() {
        var objSearch = nSearch.create({
            type: 'transaction',
            filters: [[["number","is","1"],"AND",["line","equalto","1"]]],
            columns: [nSearch.createColumn({
                name: 'internalid'
            })]
        });

        var resultSet = objSearch.run();

        resultSet.getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could it be that `haskeywords` requires an array as an input so you would need to also wrap `"1"` in parenthesis? This is just a wild guess.

Comment: @rorschach.  Thanks for the reply! `haskeywords` works (`testThatSucceeds`). `is` doesn't work (`testThatFails`).  I just tried and neither of these work: `[[["numbertext","is",['1']],"AND",["line","equalto","1"]]]` `[[["numbertext","is",('1')],"AND",["line","equalto","1"]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numbertext` field is not listed as a [supported filter](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/transaction.html). You can use it to filter your search but it may cause unexpected behaviour. You should use `number` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only unbalanced parenthesis I can see is the very first one immediately after `define` which isn't closed at the end in your example.  Not sure why that would allow the other functions to work though.

Comment: That was a copy-paste error on my part and isn't the cause of the issue.  The reason I included the `define` was so that people would know which dependency `nSearch` corresponds to.  Thanks for pointing it out; I've fixed it.